# Form submit only once with php

Tags: php, forms

I have the following tables. The one is for login and user registration and the other it will store the answers of a survey with many questions. Just for now I have 2 textboxes to test it. My aim is every user to submit only **once** the survey. So I have the following. The one table is for login and registration

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `userid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`userid`),
  KEY `userid` (`userid`),
  KEY `userid_2` (`userid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=18 ;
```

and this one is to keep the first name and the last name

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `survey` (
  `surveyid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `firstname` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`surveyid`),
  KEY `firstname` (`firstname`),
  KEY `firstname_2` (`firstname`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;
```

My login.php page is

```
<?php 
session_start();

@$username = $_POST['username'];
@$password = $_POST['pass'];

if(@$_POST['Submit']){
if($username&&$password)
{
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost","****","****") or die("Cannot Connect");
mysql_select_db("project") or die("Cannot find the database");

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'");
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
if($numrows!=0)
{
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
    {
        $dbusername = $row['username'];
        $dbpassword = $row['password'];
    }
    if($username==$dbusername&&$password==$dbpassword)
    {
        echo "You are login!!!!! Continue now with the survey <a href='mainpage.php'>here</a>";
        $_SESSION['username']=$username;
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<b>Incorrect Password!!!!</b>";
    }
}
else
    //die("That user does not exist");
    echo "<b>That user does not exist</b>";
}
else
echo "<b>You must enter a username and a password</b>";
}
?>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>   
<title>Login Page</title>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Login Page</h2>
<form name="loginform" method='POST'>

<fieldset>
<legend>Form</legend>
    <label>Username: <input type="text" name="username"/><span>*</span></label><br/>
    <label>Password: <input type="password" name="pass"/><span>*</span></label>
    <input class="placeButtons" type="reset" value='Reset'/>
    <input class="placeButtons" type="submit" name="Submit" value='Login'/>
    <a href='registration.php'>Register</a>
</fieldset>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

my page which inserts the data is

```
<?php 
session_start();

if ($_SESSION['username'])
{
echo "Welcome, ".$_SESSION['username']."! <a href='logout.php'>Logout</a>";
}
else
die("You must be logged in!!");
?>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<script src="question.js"></script>
<title>Questionnaire</title>
<style type="text/css"> 
    span {color: #FF00CC}
</style>
</head>
<body  background="images/good.jpg">
<h1>Please complete the following Survey</h1>
<form name="quiz" method="post" action="submitsurvey.php">

First Name: <input type="text" name="firstname" id="fname"/>
<p></p>
Last Name: <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lname"/>
<input type="submit" name="submitbutton" value="Go"></input>
<input type="reset" value="clear all"></input>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and finally submitsurvey.php is the page which stores the data in the database

```
<?php
session_start();

if ($_SESSION['username'])
{
echo "Welcome, ".$_SESSION['username']."! <a href='logout.php'>Logout</a>";
}
else
die("You must be logged in!!");
$con=mysql_connect ("localhost","****","****");
mysql_select_db("project",$con);
@$firstname=$_POST['firstname'];
@$lastname=$_POST['lastname'];

$s="INSERT INTO survey(`firstname`,`lastname`) VALUES ('$firstname','$lastname')";
echo "You have successfully submit your questions";
 mysql_query ($s);
?>
```

I would like your thoughts of how can I continue. As first thought is to create a foreign key of surveyid in users tables. I tried it but it was impossible to register and the reason I think is because the survey table is empty. Maybe I am completely wrong but this is just a thought

**UPDATE**
I created a lookup table but it does not get the userid and surveyid

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `lookup` (
`lookupid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`surveyid` int(11) NOT NULL,
`userid` int(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`lookupid`),
KEY `surveyid` (`surveyid`,`userid`),
KEY `userid` (`userid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

ALTER TABLE `lookup`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `lookup_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`userid`) REFERENCES `users` (`userid`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `lookup_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`surveyid`) REFERENCES `survey` (`surveyid`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about a lookup table that has 3 fields, lookupID, surveyID and userID

When they fill out the survey, add a record to the lookup table.

On the page where you load the survey, query the lookup table for the user's ID.  If it exists echo a message "Thanks, but you have already completed the survey".

Oh and by the way, your login script is a perfect example of how to fall victim to a SQL injection.

Comment: Can I have a simple example of this query which you propose me?

Comment: Dali, if you aren't able to construct a query to find if a userID exists in a database table, you need to go back and learn how.  

SO is to help people solve problems, not teach them how to do the very basics...and that is very basic

Comment: Steve, I created a lookup table with two foreign keys surveyid and userid. For users and survey page works perfectly. I can insert the data. But I do not have results in lookup table. I have to write also a query 'Insert into lookup...' with the userid and surveyid? It shouldn't automatically add these ids to the lookup table? Please take a look in my update. Maybe my lookup table is worng.

Comment: are you doing an INSERT into the lookup table?  If not, how do you expect the data to be there?

Comment: And Dali, despite it being voted down, Martin's reply below is absolutely right.  That is what I was saying about SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use MySQL, use PDO or MySQLi instead. MySQL is old, deprecated and vulnerable

Comment: should really be a comment and not an answer. not answering the OPs question